# How to check ajax request complete & send again new request using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

On page load i'm sending one AJAX using jQuery .ajax function.
After i got response from that i want to send another ajax request & it would be recursive.

So after getting previous ajax request's response i want to send another request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I try to give you just a sample

```
function recursiveAjax(url, method, dataType, ) {
  $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: method,
     dataType: dataType,
     success: function(response) {  // success function call after a successful response
         if(response) {
            recursiveAjax('script_url', 'POST', 'json');
         }
     }
  })
}
```

**Initial call:**

```
recursiveAjax('script_url', 'POST', 'json');
```

Read more about **[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** for `success()` and `complete()` method.

You can also use `.done()` method like following:

```
function recursiveAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    dataType: dataType
  }).done(function ( response ) {
    if(response) {
       recursiveAjax(...);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

refer to the `complete` or `success` parameters in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)